# Vector move constructor slower than copy constructor

Tags: c++, csv, c++11, vector, move-semantics

I'm working on my first C++ project, which is a CSV parser ([full source code here](https://github.com/AriaFallah/csv-parser/blob/master/parser.hpp)). It's at the point where it's working, and now I want to do basic refactoring / improve performance.

Currently the way the parser works is by returning each row as a `std::vector<std::string>`, and I figured that instead of allocating a new vector and a new string every time I'd just have an internal vector and internal string with reserved memory that I'd clear again and again.

That worked, and I started looking at other places where I might be doing memory allocation, and I saw this function which copies the internal vector, and then clears it:

```
auto add_row() -> std::vector<std::string> {
  auto row(m_bufvec);
  m_bufvec.clear();
  return row;
}
```

I figured that if I instead changed this line

```
auto row(m_bufvec);
```

to

```
auto row(std::move(m_bufvec));
```

It'd result in some sort of speed boost because according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector it would take constant time instead of linear. To my surprise, it made the parser significantly slower (according to my really rough benchmark of running `time ./main.o` over [this file](https://github.com/AriaFallah/csv-parser/blob/master/benchmark/sample.csv)).

I'm completely new to optimization, benchmarking, and everything else that comes with tuning C++ code. Perhaps this optimization is useless even if it worked, but regardless, I'm curious as to why `std::move` causes a slowdown. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try `auto row{ move( m_bufvec ) }; m_bufvec.reserve( row.size() ); return row;`. Basically, compared to copying this avoid the per-element copying, so should be faster.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf well that confirms that it was the capacity being emptied that caused it. The speed went back to normal, and at best was 2-3% better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you copy bufvec, its capacity is unchanged, but when you move it, its capacity is cleared. Thus, later when you fill bufvec, a logarithmic number of allocations (and log-linear element copies/moves) that are done to expand its capacity again, and such allocations can easily be your performance bottleneck.

The move version makes *that* function faster.  But it makes other code slower.  Micro optimizations do not reliably make programs faster.

---

Edit by OP:

The solution proposed by `Cheers and hth. - Alf` in the comments of `m_bufvec.reserve(row.size())` after the move fixes the problem, and confirms that the above reasoning was correct. Moreover it is more efficient, (albeit only slightly) because

> you avoid copying the items [in bufvec]. If the items are simple integer values, that doesn't matter so much. If the items are e.g. strings, with dynamic allocation, then it really does matter.

Comment: Ah I didn't know that `move` reset the capacity! I'll probably accept this soon, but I want to keep the question open just in case there are other answers I can learn from.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed the first version is expected to be faster. The reason is:

```
auto row(m_bufvec);
```

invokes the copy constuctor, which allocates the necessary memory for `row` just at once. `bufvec` also keeps its allocated memory. As a result, allocations *per-element* are minimized, and this is important because they involve an amount of *relocations*.

In the second version, `auto row(std::move(m_bufvec));` `bufvec`'s memory becomes owned by `row`, this operation is faster than the copy constructor. But as `bufvec` has lost its allocated memory, when you later fill it element by element, it will do many re-allocations and (expensive) relocation. The number of re-allocations is usually logarithmic with the final size of the vector.

EDIT

The above explains the "unexpected" results in the main question. Finally, it turns out that the "ideal" for this operation is to move then reserve immediately:

```
auto row(std::move(m_bufvec);
m_bufvec.reserve(row.size());
return row;
```

This achieves the three goals:

- no element-by-element allocation
- no useless initialization for `bufvec`
- no useless copying of elements from `m_bufvec` into `row`.

Comment: "moving from it is not a good idea", well you haven't discussed how to avoid the problem you have identified. as i see it a `reserve` call should fix that problem for the `move` code.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf good point. I thought about that, but it's actually more complicated, because ideally we want to reserve with avoiding the useless initialization, so it somehow extends beyond the present piece of code and the main question.

Comment: `reserve` does exactly that (if I understand you correctly): it reserves capacity without initializing the items. So, it's actually more simple. :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I think he means that if I have already reserved capacity earlier (which I had), then there's no reason to reset that capacity to 0 with an `std::move`, and then later expand it again. It's simpler to just avoid the `std::move` altogether.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I see now the answer in your comment in the question's section... yeah, we save the extra copy. Good point. However my analysis concisely explains the "unexpected results" of the main question. Cheers! (and health :) )

Comment: @AR7: re "no reason", you avoid copying the items. If the items are simple integer values, that doesn't matter so much. If the items are e.g. strings, with dynamic allocation, then it really does matter. Oh, they *are* strings. Then it does matter.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf yep I figured that out just now actually after reading through your other stuff over again. Thanks! I'll edit my edit lol